# How can I convert Json data that coming from Postman convert into Integers in python?

Tags: python, json, postman, mql5, metatrader5

Here I've wrote a python script using MQL5 to get total history order from MetaTrader5. here's the code,

```
from_date = datetime(2020, 1, 1)
to_date = datetime.now()
history_orders = mt.history_orders_total(from_date, to_date )
print(history_orders)
```

what my requirement is I need to get from_date and to_date parameter from user. so I passed these parameter from Postman Using POST request.here is the payload

```
{
     "fromDate" : "2020, 1, 1",
     "toDate": "2020, 11, 8"
}
```

And it says,

> history_orders = mt.history_orders_total(datetime(fromDate),
> datetime(toDate)) TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

how can I convert these Json payloads into integers in python?
here my code.

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def historyOrderTotal():
    fromDate = None
    toDate = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fromDate = request.json['fromDate']
        toDate = request.json['toDate']

    mt.initialize()

    history_orders = mt.history_orders_total(datetime(fromDate), datetime(toDate))
    print(history_orders)
```

Comment: A better question is how would I parse/convert strings into dates in Python. And then you would have found many more answers as well. In a sense, my answer below is really about clarifying your intent, based on my understanding of your question.

Comment: I also hope you have something to handle what happens if the request method is not 'POST'. Would you still want to get the orders? Should that orders logic only be within the 'if' statement?

Comment: You are not doing the same thing as me at all, you are doing `datetime(str)` which is invalid, it implies `datetime(year='2020, 1, 1')`, whereas year must be an int value.  I first parse the string using `strptime`, which converts it into a `datetime` object automatically based on the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You care less about the integers, you want `datetime` objects. You have decided that you want `<year>, <month>, <day>` as your incoming serialised JSON format for dates.

So you might do:

```py
from datetime import datetime

pattern = "%Y, %m, %d"
from_date = datetime.strptime(fromDate, pattern)
to_date = datetime.strptime(toDate, pattern)
```

You might want to add validations, e.g. `assert from_date <= to_date` etc. depending on your use case.

I also recommend you look into ISO 8601 date formats, as a more standardised way of serialising dates.

Debug Notes, try this based on your comments:

```py
@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def historyOrderTotal():
    fromDate = None
    toDate = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fromDate = request.json['fromDate']
        toDate = request.json['toDate']
        print("json-from:", fromDate)
        print("json-to:", toDate)
        pattern = "%Y, %m, %d"
        from_date = datetime.strptime(fromDate, pattern)
        to_date = datetime.strptime(toDate, pattern)
        print("parsed-from:", from_date)
        print("parsed-to:", to_date)
        if mt.initialize():
            history_orders = mt.history_orders_total(from_date, to_date)
            print("history-orders", history_orders)
        else:
            print("initialize() failed, error code =", mt.last_error())
    else:
        print(">> Not a POST request")
```

Comment: thank you for your comment! but it won't work I already tried that and I'm running out of ideas. here is the documentation [history_orders_total](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5historyorderstotal_py) @kva1966

Comment: Can you actually post the output of both your trial and what the error was? I read that doco before answering your question.

Comment: See my comments on your question. You haven't tried the same thing at all.

Comment: the code that you gave is not throwing errors but it shows total history orders as 0!
here is the postman output
 `{
    "orderHistoryTotal": 0
}`

Comment: You'll need to give more info, or I can't help further. What are the to and from dates being parsed as? Are you sure you have orders during that period? Have you tried actually just doing it with hardcoded dates? You'll need to actually write this out.

Comment: And the Code That I wrote based on your suggestion,
`@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def historyOrderTotal():
    fromDate = None
    toDate = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fromDate = request.json['fromDate']
        toDate = request.json['toDate']

    pattern = "%Y, %m, %d"
    from_date = datetime.strptime(fromDate, pattern)
    print(from_date)
    print(type(from_date))
    to_date = datetime.strptime(toDate, pattern)

    history_orders = mt.history_orders_total(from_date, to_date)
    print(history_orders)`

Comment: yes I've tried doing it with hardcoded dates and the output is : Total history orders= 62

Comment: See my answer update, the Debug Notes, see if that finds your problem. The issue should not be in the actual parsing logic (which I have tested).

Comment: Thank you for your effort it's still working but the output is still 0!! @kva1966

Comment: Dude, show me the print output, haha. I can't see what you see! I put in all those print statements so I get to see exactly what is happening, but only if you post the output!

Comment: here's the print output, 
`json-from: 2020, 1, 1
json-to: 2020, 11, 8
parsed-from: 2020-01-01 00:00:00
parsed-to: 2020-11-08 00:00:00
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2021 11:22:57] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
history-orders 0`

Comment: Thank you. What does `history_orders1 = mt.history_orders_total(datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime(2020, 11, 8))` give you? If it's still 0, check your history once more. Try different dates, too.

Comment: You should also make sure that MT is actually initialised, since `mt.initialise(..)` just returns False on error, it does not die. You need to check for the return value, as per the sample code for `history_orders_total`. See also https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5initialize_py

Comment: I have updated the debug code with the initialisation check.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with initialise() but there is something wrong with to_date! because I run the same code like this:
` history_orders = mt.history_orders_total(from_date, datetime.now())
  print(history_orders)`
and this code gives me the output : 62
but when i run the code like this:
`history_orders = mt.history_orders_total(from_date, to_date)
 print(history_orders)`
and its says output : 0
and I'm Confused by this!! do you have any idea?

Comment: Try a different date range, for example, just use 2020-08-11 to now. If the from_date parsed properly, and to_date is identically parsed, and MT is being initialised, then only the actual history orders remains: make sure the orders actually are there for the period.

Comment: yes, it worked, and there isn't any wrong with the code it's something with postman application. but your guidance helps me through this. but I couldn't vote up because I don't have enough reputation but if you can vote up my post I think I'll be able to vote!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working, and thanks for accepting the answer. It's usually a good idea to narrow things down as much as possible, e.g. use a test without any of the web service layer, just to make sure the core logic is working. Then, add more moving parts to it.